AVX2 Code crashes when instructions are combined
I was trying to shift zeros from Unsigned to signed range
i.e,. [0,255] -> [127, -128]
To perform this below operation
__m256i shifted = _mm256_xor_si256(a, _mm256_set1_epi8(-128));
__m256i maskCount = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(shifted, zerosShifted);

when I wrote the code like this, It Runs
    __m256i temp1 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    __m256i temp2 = _mm256_set1_epi8(-128);
    __m256i zerosShifted = _mm256_xor_si256(temp1,temp2);

but when I wrote like this, It crashes saying Illegal Instruction
__m256i zerosShifted = _m256_xor_si256(_mm256_setzero_si256(),_mm256_set1_epi8(-128));

PS: I know there is no need to shift zeros to -128, I can set -128 directly to the register but just to know the root cause analysis.
The complete AVX2 code looks like this:
__m256i *pIn0, *pOut0;
            __m256i a;
            __m256i zerosShifted = _mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_setzero_si256(), _mm256_set1_epi8(-128));
            __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi8(1);
            __m256i zeros = _mm256_setzero_si256();
            for (int x = 1; x < height - 1 ; x++)
            {
                int y = 1;
                for (; y < width - 32; y+=32)
                {
                    a = _MM256_LOAD_SI256((__m256i*)&boundary_image_array[x*width + y]);

                    __m256i shifted = _mm256_xor_si256(a, _mm256_set1_epi8(-128));
                    __m256i maskCount = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(shifted, zerosShifted);

                    maskCount = _mm256_and_si256(maskCount, ones);

                    __m256i imageAgg = _mm256_blendv_epi8(a, zeros, maskCount);

                    __m256i pixelCount = _mm256_sad_epu8(maskCount, zeros);
                    __m256i imgAggSum = _mm256_sad_epu8(imageAgg, zeros);

                    boundary_pixel_count_r += _mm256_extract_epi64(pixelCount, 0) + _mm256_extract_epi64(pixelCount, 1)
                        + _mm256_extract_epi64(pixelCount, 2) + _mm256_extract_epi64(pixelCount, 3);

                    boundary_grad_image_agg += _mm256_extract_epi64(imgAggSum, 0) + _mm256_extract_epi64(imgAggSum, 1)
                        + _mm256_extract_epi64(imgAggSum, 2) + _mm256_extract_epi64(imgAggSum, 3);
                }
                for (; y < width - 1 ; y++)
                {
                    //! Determine the boundary stats:
                    if (boundary_image_array[x*width + y] > 0)
                    {
                        boundary_pixel_count_r++;
                        boundary_grad_image_agg += boundary_image_array[x*width + y];
                    }
                }
            }


The problem is that 0 should be transformed to 127 and 255 to -128?  Does not 127 - x do that?

Your final example has m256_xor_si256 without the leading underscore.  Is this correct?  Could you show us the assembly code resulting from these examples?  What compiler in what version on what platform do you use?

In all 3 major compilers (gcc, clang, MSVC) both of your examples appear to work and produce the correct (and identical) result. (I've changed m256_xor_si256 to _mm256_xor_si256 in your second one, I assume that's a typo.) 'Illegal instruction' indicates to me more that other parts of your code have undefined behavior and your actual problem is likely somewhere completely different, while this code change just triggers the compiler to behave differently. (Not returning a value in a function often triggers 'illegal instruction' on gcc in my experience.)

m256_xor_si256 to _mm256_xor_si256 that was really a typo, I also believe that problem is somewhere else and this code is triggering the compiler to behave like this, @chris_se I'm editing this question with complete code, pls tell if anything suspicious.

@convoluxon Is it possible for you to produce a [mcve] that exhibits the issue and can be compiled individually?  Your code does not look suspicious and is missing too many bits to be compiled.

Which illegal instruction executed?  If it's ud2, that's the compiler intentionally putting an illegal instruction on a path of execution that has compile-time-visible UB.  If it's an instruction like vpxor, then your CPU (or virtual machine) doesn't support AVX2.  Use a debugger like GDB to disassemble at the point where your code crashes.  GDB disas

Are you compiling with optimization disabled?  Only in an unoptimized build would I expect a difference between three statements with temp1 and temp2 vs. one statement.  Also, those aren't "instructions", they're "intrinsics" (functions).  Instructions are what the compiler emits to implement your source.

Yes ,@PeterCordes the crash happens on the machine which don't have AVX2 instructions there only the code crashes. can you tell the reason behind that, thanks for correction to intrinsics.

@convoluxon Your code uses AVX2 intrinsics and thus requires AVX2 to work.

@fuz that anyways will not led the compiler to crash

Wait... the compiler crashes?  Not your code?

This needs a [mcve] of exactly what crash you're talking about, including build commands, and info on what compiler / version and OS and CPU.
